# Excel converts 1/1 as date (DD.MM.YYYY)

Tags: php, excel

I am exporting a CSV from web app and I have a column Format which can be for example 1/1 or 1/6... and Excel converts it as 1.1.2017. or 1.6.2017.

This is my function for export:

```
public function exportCSVPrint($id)
    {
        $tablePrint = DB::connection('mysql2')->table('mc_schaltdaten_print')->select('s_magazin', 'datum', 's_ausgabe', 's_ausrichtung', 's_jahrgang', 's_format', 's_seite', 's_seiten', 'brutto', 'pzn')->where('spotid', $id)->get();
        $csv        = \League\Csv\Writer::createFromFileObject(new \SplTempFileObject());

        $header = [Lang::get('language.magazine'), Lang::get('language.date'), Lang::get('language.ausgabeVersion'), Lang::get('language.seite'), Lang::get('language.seiten'), 'Format', Lang::get('language.ausrichtung'), Lang::get('language.anzeigenPreis')];
        $csv->setDelimiter(';');
        $csv->insertOne($header);

        foreach ($tablePrint as $t) {
            $rows = [
                [$t->s_magazin, $t->datum, $t->s_ausgabe, $t->s_seite, $t->s_seiten, $t->s_format, $t->s_ausrichtung, $t->brutto],
            ];

            $csv->insertAll($rows);
        }
        $csv->output($id . '.csv');
    }
```

How can I get it as original 1/1, not date format?

Comment: Congratulations. You just discovered that Excel sucks, and it sucks especially hard when handling CSV formatted data. Sadly, the problem you're describing is actually one of the less serious bugs with Excel's CSV handling. Beware that there are several others that are much *much* worse.

Comment: Yes, MS Excel does try to "second guess" what a value means when importing csv filed, and it doesn't always work as expected. That's why CSV isn't the best format to use when you plan to view the file using MS Excel.

Answer (score 1):

Annoying isn't it?

Excel "helpfully" assumes that you've typed a date, with the year appropriately defaulted, when you type something like `a / b`.

You can retain the original text if you prefix the string with the single quotation character `'`.

Comment: Annoying, indeed! ;D How can I insert quote in array, because in my case `$t->s_format` is an array member.